# How to write query to display images in Listview?

Tags: java, android, sql, listview

I have Listview on MainActivity. On Listview must image and text. I write query and successfully texts are displaying. I make ListCategoryAdapter which extends BaseAdapter. All tutorials in Internet with arrays, none of them working with DB. Here is Adapter.

```
public class ListCategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Category> cats;
    Context context;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    String stt;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    public ListCategoryAdapter(Context context1, List<Category> list){
        if (list != null){
            this.cats = list;
            this.context = context1;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cats.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cats.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView2;
        TextView txtCateg;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cat_adapter, null);
        }

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        final Category cat = cats.get(position);

        holder.txtCateg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCateg);
        holder.txtCateg.setText(cat.getTitle());

        holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.imageView2.setImageResource(cat.getImage());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class RecordHolder{
        TextView txtCateg;
        ImageView imageView2;
    }
}
```

Here is Database where from calls text and image

```
public List<Category> categories(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    String ss = "select * from category";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(ss, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Resources resources = mContext.getResources();

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        category.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        category.setImage(cursor.getInt(2));  
        categoryList.add(category);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }  db.close();

    return categoryList;
}
```

Here is Category class

```
public class Category {

    int id;
    int image;
    String title;

    public Category(int image, String title, int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Category() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you saving images in db?

Comment: "All tutorials in Internet with arrays, none of them working with DB" then use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, do not use `BaseAdapter`